# Oracle SQL Developer, I keep getting the query in the .CSV file

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to export the results from a query in a `.csv` file. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and the `/*csv*/` tag. I get the data formatted fine, but I also get the query. My .csv file looks [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BVpY.png).

What options should I use so I only get the data? I've tried `SET TERM`, `SET ECHO`, and `SET VERIFY` and nothing works so far. Thank you in advance for any helpful ideas.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the original poster of this question. I've searched and couldn't find anything like what I'm asking.

Comment: Please disregard the above comment. I found the link and it worked. Thanks!